# Running node.js on a website but not on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, localhost

I made an online multiplayer game. I works perfectly when I run it with node.js command prompt on localhost:3000. But when I try to run it on the website it is not doing what my app.js file says it to do.  my questions are;

How can I make my node.js project run on my website rather than on localhost? 
What will the port be instead of 3000?
Can I do this by uploading some file into my website via ftp?

Here is my app.js file

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var usernumm = 0;
var usernum1 = [];

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){


var endpoint = socket.manager.handshaken[socket.id].address;
console.log('***New connection from ' + endpoint.address + ':' +     endpoint.port);

usernumm++;
io.sockets.emit('usernum', usernumm);
usernum1[usernumm] =  endpoint.port;
console.log('usernum'+usernumm+'geldi'+findusernum());


socket.on('button1socket', function(){

    io.sockets.emit('button1f', findusernum() );
    console.log('user '+findusernum()+' pressed a button');

});
socket.on('buttonclickable', function(){

    io.sockets.emit('buttonclickable1', findusernum() );

});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    usernumm--;
    io.sockets.emit('usernum', usernumm);
    //sockets[usernum] = socket.port;
    console.log('***Client disconnected');
});


//finds number of online users
function findusernum(){
    for(var i = 0; i<9;i++){
        if(usernum1[i] == endpoint.port){return i;}else{}
        }
}


});
```

Comment: [Going live with Node](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/going-live-with-node--net-33923)

Comment: I'd recommend Heroku, basically you just upload it and It should run.
You should also note this:
`var port = process.env.PORT || 3000`

this lets your server run depending on the environment port.

Comment: @MuliYulzary thanks for the comment,it helped. Heroku is awesome. and this(`process.env.PORT || 3000`) also helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var httpServer = require('http').Server(app);
var socketServer = require('socket.io')(httpServer);

var ip = 'iphere';
var port = 80;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

socketServer.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("A Client has connected.");
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log("A Client has disconnected.");
    });
});

httpServer.listen(port, ip, function(){
    console.log("Listening to "+ip+":"+port);
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ip:port/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket;
        try{
            socket = io("http://ip:port/", {'forceNew':true });
            socket.on('connect', function(error){
                if(error){

                }
            });
        }catch(e){

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

after you have specified your ip and port

port forward the port you have specified to live your website/game using your router

then you can visit it with http://yourpublicip:port/

if its port 80 then visit the page without the port.

Comment: It didn't work. Don't I need to install something like node etc. on my website ?

Comment: No, you have nothing to install, i have edited my answer, on the 'iphere', put in your private ip. get it by typing in `cmd` `ipconfig`